# the returned SDL_cursor from SDL_GetCursor() can't be used with SDL_GetMouseState()?

Tags: c++, mouse, sdl

I'm trying to get the x, y, and state of my mouse in SDL. I tried using the lines

```
int mstate, mx, my = 0;
mstate, mx, my = SDL_GetCursor().SDL_GetMouseState();
```

But it gives me the error

> C:[path]\particletest2\main.cpp|107|error: request for member `SDL_GetMouseState' in`SDL_GetCursor()', which is of non-class type `SDL_Cursor*'|

Is there any way I can get this to work? It seems like a waste to create a SDL_cursor object when SDL_GetCursor() should be creating one to return for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlgetcursor.html

`SDL_GetCursor()` returns a pointer and so you need to use the `->` operator to access its member.

Responding to your reply:

I think

```
mstate, mx, my = SDL_GetCursor()->SDL_GetMouseState();
```

is a problem if it wasn't incorrectly pasted. I do not think that this is doing what you think it should be doing, and I am not really sure what you think it should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put pointers to yours variables and then this gonna have the coordinates

```
int x,y;
SDL_GetMouseState(&x,&y);
```

now x and y have the coordinates of your cursor